# Android preference rangebar

Tags: android, settings, preference

I want to implement a custom preference widget in my preference activity : a RangeBar (a seekbar-like able to retain two data and create a range)

I read about how to implement a custom preference widget but it seems that you can only safe one data, how could I proceed to safe two ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only store a single data type. However, you can combine several settings into a single type, e.g., multiple color components into a single `int` or other settings in a (JSON) `String`.

Comment: So I think that I am going to store as "min:max: in a string, I just need to figure out how to implement this :)